# Virtual Machine Manager - Windows 10 VM Keeps going into a Paused state

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I have Windows 10 virtual machine that keeps going into a `Paused` state. Numerous times I've attempted to do some minor windows updates to it, but each time I try, about 5 or 10 minutes into the update, the virtual machine pauses, and you cannot un-pause it after that.

For example, this morning, I started the VM at exactly 7:35:20 AM. At 7:41 AM, the VM went into a paused state, and this is a screenshot of where it froze:

[image]

The virtual hard drive has plenty of free space and I've allocated [8 gibibytes](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/#8GiB) of RAM. So, I don't understand why it keeps pausing.

I created this virtual machine using [Virtual Machine Manager](https://virt-manager.org/).

I have no clue what's causing this issue. Why would a virtual machine, with plenty of RAM and disk space, auto-pause, after running fine for the first few minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason why a VM can get forced into a paused state is when the underlying host filesystem has filled up. (A real problem with overprovisioning.)

Check the filesystem where this VM's disk image is stored

Comment: Another thing that fooled me, was that the virtual hard drive's file showed to be [211.5GiB](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/#211.5GiB) in my file browser, with Windows 10 reporting [165GB of free space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCzCV.png). Since this file was already seemly taking up the full space I originally allocated, I didn't think running out of disk space on the host-drive was even possible, because I thought it was already using the max space originally allocated from the beginning.